Finding quad faces in a planar graph / 2D mesh
Description:
I have a set of coordinate points and an adjacency list that describes how each point (node) is connected to other points. Using these, I plotted a graph using NetworkX in Python.
Here are the points and the adjacency list:
points = [
    [1449, 1427], [1568, 1349], [1828, 1262], [1054, 1294], [1236, 1186],
    [1432, 1124], [1754, 1032], [2122, 968], [2591, 953], [790, 957],
    [1069, 881], [1720, 738], [2183, 691], [2633, 723], [557, 495],
    [878, 465], [1238, 433], [1690, 412], [2229, 395], [2705, 368],
    [432, 116], [772, 74], [1234, 27], [1680, 0], [2267, 21]
]

adjacency_list = [
    [2,5], [1,3,6], [2,7], [5,10], [1,4,6,11], [2,5,7], [3,6,8,12],
    [7,9,13], [8,14], [4,11,15], [5,10,16], [7,13,18], [8,12,14,19],
    [9,13,20], [10,16,21], [11,17,15,22], [16,18,23], [12,17,19,24],
    [13,18,20,25], [19,14], [15,22], [21,16,23], [17,22], [18,25], [19,24]
]

I used the following Python code to visualize the graph:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

# Create a new graph
G = nx.Graph()

# Add nodes with positions
for i, point in enumerate(points):
    G.add_node(i + 1, pos=point)

# Add edges
for i, connections in enumerate(adjacency_list):
    for j in connections:
        G.add_edge(i + 1, j)

# Get node positions
pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos')

nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_color='green', node_size=300, font_size=8, font_color='white')

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

The resulting graph is shown below:

Objective:
I want to determine which faces are formed by the nodes in this graph. Specifically, I'm only interested in the faces that are quadrilaterals (i.e., faces formed by exactly 4 nodes/vertices).
For example, face 1 marked in the image is represented by the nodes [1, 2, 5, 6]. So, for this example, the output should be:
faces = [
    [1,2,6,5], [2,3,7,6], [4,5,11,10], [7,8,13,12], [8,9,14,13], [10,11,16,15], [12,13,19,18],
   [13,14,20,19], [15,16,22,21], [16,17,23,22], [18,19,25,24]

]
Considerations:
Face 1 (and similarly for the others) can be any of the valid faces (I chose this order to make it consistent with the image).
Note that adjacency_list  does not necessarily list the nodes in a particular order (clockwise or counterclockwise).

Is the graph guaranteed to always be that nice? Or sometimes you have intersecting edges? For the graph you posted it should be pretty easy to do. Take a random node: 7. Get the neighbors: [3,6,8,12]. Now for each neighbor calculate their neighbors and look for shared neighbors other than 7, so for example nodes 8 and 12 share a neighbor: 13, so you have a face formed by [7,8,12,13]. On the other hand 3 and 6 share a neighbor: 2, so another face is [7,3,6,2]. Now instead of taking random nodes iterate over all of them in order and you will be able to compute all faces.

There won't be any intersection edges! The graphs is much bigger but it will look something like this always.

Ok, then just implement what I mentioned in my comment and you are done. If the graph is very very big you might need to do some tweaks to improve efficiency, like, if face 3 is already computed using node 4, you can prune some branches when expanding nodes 5 and 10 for efficiency.

thanks for the answer, I will try to implement and put the final code here if it works!

If I understand well, you are trying to find all simple cycles of size 4 in your graph.
It is quite straightforward with NetworkX:
for c in nx.simple_cycles(G):
    if len(c)==4: print(c)


You may need to know a bit more about graph theory (and specifically cycles) or check the NetworkX documentation on Cycles.
Cheers!

Sorry for the late reply! I tried your solution but for my real graph (58000 nodes) it was very very slow... But for small grpahs it works great!

It is mainly because the algorithm checks for all possible cycles within your graph, including those with size > 4. It doesn't make much difference for small graphs (such as the one shown in your original post) but it is indeed very inefficient for large graphs. As stated in the documentation, the time complexity is O((n + e)(c + 1)) for
n nodes, e edges and c simple circuits. You can use the length_bound parameter to limit the search: for c in nx.simple_cycles(G, length_bound=4):. Hope that helps!

Using Cincinnatus ideas I created this code:
from itertools import combinations

def find_quadrilateral_faces(G):
    faces = set()
    for node in G.nodes():
        neighbors = list(G.neighbors(node))
        for i, j in combinations(neighbors, 2):
            common_neighbors = set(G.neighbors(i)) & set(G.neighbors(j)) - {node}
            for common_neighbor in common_neighbors:
                face = frozenset([node, i, j, common_neighbor])
                faces.add(face)
    return list(faces)

def sort_face_points(face, points):
    # Convert to numpy array 
    pts = np.array([points[i] for i in face])
    
    # Find centroid
    cent = pts.mean(axis=0)
    
    # Sort points based on their angle from centroid
    sorted_pts = sorted(face, key=lambda p: np.arctan2(*(np.array(points[p]) - cent)[::-1]))
    
    return sorted_pts

# Find all quadrilateral faces
quadrilateral_faces = find_quadrilateral_faces(G)

# Sort the points in each face
quadrilateral_faces = [[int(node) for node in face] for face in quadrilateral_faces]
quadrilateral_faces = [sort_face_points(face, P) for face in quadrilateral_faces]

